# Mapping block_device to device struct

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In linux kernel how to map `block_device` to `device` struct? In other words if we have a `block_device` struct how we can get corresponding `device` struct?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that shortest way for me is to find `bdev_map` pointer and perform a `kobj_lookup(bdev_map, inode->i_rdev, &dummy)` operation. This returns a `kobject` that correspons to block device (`i_rdev`).

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way seems to be `block_device->bd_disk->driverfs_dev` .

Also possible is `block_device->bd_inode_backing_dev_info->dev`

Yes both bd_disk and bd_inode_backing_dev_info members can be null depending from where you try to acess them and your kobj_lookup call also provides a mapping, though by request rather than through existing structural hierachy.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to be an easy task. The next problem is that the `bd_disk` is NULL. I have an `inode` of block device file and use bdget to get a pointer to `block_device` struct. The pointer is valid but `bd_disk` is not :(

Comment: `block_device->backing_dev_info->device` there is no such chain

Comment: Apologies accidently specified type instead of field name.

Comment: No, there no such a chain too :)